# Does the increase of electromagnetic waves in the atmosphere made by man help increase the earths temperature?

Tags: electromagnetism

If the devices we are using emit radio waves, microwaves, wi-fi, even the electricity and lights we use at night are increasing the electromagnetic fields on earth, is it measurable? One device may not add up to much. But collectively does it add up to enough energy or particle vibration to alter the temperature of the earth or the atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the atmosphere is roughly $5 \times 10^{18} \rm{kg}$, its heat capacity is $\approx 1 \rm{kJ/(kg.K)}$ so to raise the temeprature of that much mass by only $1\rm{mK}$ you would need $\approx 1 \rm{kJ/(kg.K)} \times 5 \times 10^{18} \rm{kg} \times 1\rm{mK} = 5 \times 10^{18} \rm {J}$.

The US electricity capacity is $\approx 16 \times 10^{18} \rm {W}$ so if the system was a closed one you could raise the temperature of the atmosphere on the order of a few $\rm{mK}$ if all the electricity was used for that purpose all the time. To get a fuller picture note that a high power radar sends out maybe a 10MW pulse but its length is only $1 \mu \rm s$ so the total energy of the pulse is $10\rm J$, that ain't much. I do not believe the temperature rise is measurable...

Comment: Thank you, I did not think of a open or closed system,